# Classes using Inheritance

Tags: c++

Need some help with inheritance. I have to write the class named `Skater` that inherits the class `Contact`. `Skater` has the additional `double` member variable called `personalBest`.

I wrote the class but I can't understand how to add `personalBest` to `toString` function to output it. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;

class Contact
{

private:
    string name;
    string email;

public:

    Contact();
    Contact(string nom, string elecMail){name = nom; email = elecMail;}
    string getName()const {return name;};
    string getEmail()const {return email;}
    void setName(string nomChange){name = nomChange;}
    void setEmail(string emailUpdate){email = emailUpdate;}
    string tostring () {return name + " : " + email;}

};

class Skater : public Contact
{
public:
    double personalBest;
    Skater(string name, string email) : Contact(name, email){}
    void setPerBest(double pBest){personalBest = pBest;}
    double getPerBest()const {return personalBest;}
};


int main() 
{
    Contact one("Mary", "papemary@fhda.edu");
    cout << one.tostring() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Skater sk("Polina Edwards", "edwardsp@sharksice.com");// should be ("Polina Edwards", "edwardsp@sharksice.com", 58.2)
    cout << sk.tostring() << endl;             
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: declare `toString` virtual and override in the `Skater` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sholud declare `tostring()` as `virtual` in the base `Contact` class:

```
virtual string tostring() {...}
```

override in Skater and implement here the specific behavior .

Answer (score 2):

Just declare `toString` as `virtual` in `Contact` and override it in `Skater` class:

```
class Contact{
 public:
  virtual string toString(){ return name + " : " + email;}
  //other members
};



class Skater:public Contact{
  public:
   string toString() override { 
     return Contact::toString() + "anything";//get return value from parent and append anything you want
   }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `toString` as a virtual method that will allow to customize logic hidden in function with same signature

```
class Contact
{

public:

  //...
  virtual string toString () { return name + " : " + email;}
                   ^
           // better use a camel case

};
```

And override as desired

```
#include <sstream>

class Skater : public Contact
{
public:
  //...
  string toString () override {
                      ^^^^
                      // be explicit about this

       std::stringstream sstm;
       sstm << name << ":" << email << personalBest;
       result = sstm.str();
};
```

You can also return simply  `Contact::toString() + personalBest` in overriden method.

Comment: why duplicate code? I am not the downvoter, in case u r wondering

Comment: @RakibulHasan deprecated